# Unexpected transition behaviour D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to loop over a three-fold D3 transition. For some reason the last command seems to be ignored by the script and I am not sure why.

The circle in the below script should diminish in radius and transition to white colour fill. I am not sure why it isn't -and nothing is cropping up in the console..?

Any ideas -and hoping it isn't something ridiculous. http://jsfiddle.net/Guill84/ww1r42ym/

Full code of transition:

```
function transitionx(size) {

   marker.transition()
     .duration(7500)
     .ease('quad')
     .style("fill", "red")
     .attr("r", size)
     .each("end", function() {
       marker.transition()
         .attr("r", size * 1.2)
         .duration(3000)
         .each("end", function() {
           marker.transition()
             .attr("r", size / 1.2)
             .duration(3000)
             .style("fill", "white")
             .each("end", transitionx(size))
         })
     })
 }
```

Comment: *"and hoping it isn't something ridiculous"*... well, not ridiculous, but just something that I believe happened to everyone at some point in his/her JS learning: executing a function immediately when you didn't mean to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
.each("end", transitionx(size))
```

You're calling `transitionx` immediately and passing its result.

If `transitionx` had no arguments, this would work:

```
.each("end", transitionx)
```

But, since `transitionx` has arguments, what you're doing right now is equivalent to:

```
.each("end", transitionx())
```

**Solution**: You'll have to wrap it in a function:

```
.each("end", function() {
    transitionx(size)
})
```

Here is your code with that change (I divided all durations by 10, to make it quicker):

```js
var size = 40

//Create a sized SVG surface within viz:
var sampleSVG = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 200)
    .attr("height", 200);

//Add to the svg surface a circle, with size position, 
var marker =
    sampleSVG.append("circle")
    .style("stroke", "gray")
    .style("fill", "white")
    .attr("r", size)
    .attr("cx", 50)
    .attr("cy", 50)

transitionx(size);
//give the object some behaviour:
function transitionx(size) {

    marker.transition()
        .duration(750)
        .ease('quad')
        .style("fill", "red")
        .attr("r", size)
        .each("end", function() {
            marker.transition()
                .attr("r", size * 1.2)
                .duration(300)
                .each("end", function() {
                    marker.transition()
                        .attr("r", size / 1.2)
                        .duration(300)
                        .style("fill", "white")
                        .each("end", function() {
                            transitionx(size)
                        })
                })
        })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```